# How many digits can I store using money, double, float types in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, laravel-5, sqldatatypes

I don't know much about Postgres. I just want to know that suppose using int we can store 8 digits then same using money types or float types how many digits we can store?

I have search on internet too and find this : https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/datatype-money.html

And what is range  ?? like `-92233720368547758.08 to +92233720368547758.07`

Comment: Yes, that is the range for `NUMBER` columns in Postgres.  Do you have a question for us?

Comment: I would strongly suggest to **NOT** use the money type. It has several problems and not advantages. Using `decimal` (or `numeric`)  is the much better choice.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen You mean `money`, not `number`, right?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Yes, I meant $$$.  Apprently, I _don't_ have my money on my mind LOL :P

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, thanks for your time

Comment: This video has a good introduction on data types including numeric ones: https://archive.fosdem.org/2018/schedule/event/postgresql_a_crash_course/